# How to add "web application" to idea settings

Tags: intellij-idea, web-applications, war

I am going to make "war" file for my Java project.
By I don't have enought experience in idea.
As I [read](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-web-application-support.html), I should activate web application in "Frameworks Support".
But I don't have this point. How can I add it here? 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Also I tried to find this plugin, but can't